# Symfony project works local, needs /web to work online

Tags: php, webserver, composer-php, symfony

I was wondering why my Symfony when i run it offline works fine using the build in web server which generates this link http://127.0.0.1:8000. When i upload my project to my external web server I need to put /web in the link in order to make it work, but this destroys all my image path's using this code:

```
<img src="{{ asset('../images/educationLogo.png') }}"/>
```

Is it possible to remove the /web online and to make symfony work just as it works local? I read on the internet you need to use the command composer update, but i cannot do that on the external webserver.

suggestions??

Comment: Most likely, your virtualhost isn't configured right. Can you post it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `web/` directory should be your web server root. All other directories (`vendor/`, `src/`, etc.) should be outside your web server root in order to protect them (nobody should be able to access the contents of these files, as they contain sensitive information).

*Tip: If you need to follow a specific directory name (e.g. `public_html`) for your server root, see the [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-the-web-directory) on how to rename the `web/` directory.*

Answer (score 1):

@WouterJ 's answer is correct. I suggest you stay with you `web/` folder and place images under it. So:

```
web/images/educationLogo.png
```

And place everything else you need to serve under the web directory. Otherwise, you will make you life difficult.